# KOMA and customized (hanging) indentation of listed references

Tags: biblatex, indentation, koma-script, paragraphs

I am trying to achieve a hanging indent in a list of references which I called through `\fullcite{key1,key2}`. Each of the two reference is supposed to begin in a newline, which I achieved through `\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\\}`

But what I cannot get working is a customization of the indentation of the lines (to facilitate the reading of the listed references, especially if there are more than only two as in this example).

My current result looks like this:

[image]

The desired result looks like this:

[image]

You see the difference is in the hanging indentation of the listed references. Why I am posting this here today is that I can't get *any* indentation to work with KOMA. I cannot even add a space at the beginning of each new line by using something like this `\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\\\quad}`. Is there something in KOMA which prevents tampering with the indentation? (Okay, when I use `\indent` (i.e. `\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\\\indent}`), I indeed get an indentation, but it is not hanging...)

The MWE is the following:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%
\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp,backend=biber,abbreviate=false,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%
@article{bayer:1997,
    Author = {Greg Bayer},
    Journalsubtitle = {A Journal for Ancient Philosophy and Science},
    Journaltitle = {Apeiron},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {109--142},
    Title = {Coming to Know Principles in \mkbibemph{Posterior Analytics} II 19},
    Volume = {30},
    Year = {1997}}
@book{bolotin:1998,
    Annote = {copied only the first chapter},
    Author = {David Bolotin},
    Location = {Albany},
    Publisher = {State University of New York Press},
    Subtitle = {With Particular Attention to the Role of His Manner of Writing},
    Title = {An Approach to Aristotle's Physics},
    Year = {1998}}
@inproceedings{broadie:2004,
    Author = {Sarah Broadie},
    Pages = {123--150},
    Crossref = {dehaas:mansfeld:2004},
    Subtitle = {Distinguishing Alteration -- Substantial Change, Elemental Change, and First Matter in \mkbibemph{GC}},
    Title = {\mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I.4}}
@inproceedings{bruschnwig:2004,
    Author = {Jacques Brunschwig},
    Crossref = {dehaas:mansfeld:2004},
    Pages = {25--63},
    Subtitle = {A False Start?},
    Title = {\mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I.1}}
@proceedings{dehaas:mansfeld:2004,
    Editor = {{Frans A.\,J.} {de Haas} and Jaap Mansfeld},      Location = {Oxford},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {Aristotle's \mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I},
    Year = {2004}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
\newcommand*{\mything}[3]{\noindent\textbf{#1}\\Texts: \fullcite{#2}.\\Literature: \fullcite{#3}.\\[1em]}
%
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\\}
%
\begin{document}
\mything{Title text foo bar}{bayer:1997,bolotin:1998}{broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004}
\mything{Title text foo bar}{bayer:1997,bolotin:1998,broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004}{broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004}
\end{document}
```

BTW:  I thought about using `biblatex` quickly. I dismissed it because with the above `\mything`-command I am trying to structure my teaching documents. In the end I would have roughly 12 times 2 (=24) bibliographies. I then thought it would perhaps be easier if I do it simply with the `\fullcite` command. But, of course, I'd be open for approaches with bibliographies too especially as this was my first thought, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this (revised):

```
\newcommand{\mything}[3]{%
  \parindent 0pt
  \textbf{#1}\par
  \renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\par
    \parshape=2 2em\dimexpr\hsize - 2em\relax 4em\dimexpr\hsize - 4em\relax}%
  \parshape=2
    2em\dimexpr\hsize - 2em\relax
    4em\dimexpr\hsize - 4em\relax
  \hspace*{-2em}% <-- negate \parshape for first paragraph
  \fullcite[Texts:][]{#2}.
  \par
  \parshape=2
    2em\dimexpr\hsize - 2em\relax
    4em\dimexpr\hsize - 4em\relax
  \hspace*{-2em}% <-- negate \parshape for first paragraph
  \fullcite[Literature:][]{#3}.
}
```

Here, we are keeping the redefinition of `\multicitedelim` local, relying on the 'prenote' optional argument to `\fullcite`, and making use of the low-level `\parshape` command.  MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-comp, backend=biber, abbreviate=false,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
%
@article{bayer:1997,
    Author = {Greg Bayer},
    Journalsubtitle = {A Journal for Ancient Philosophy and Science},
    Journaltitle = {Apeiron},
    Number = {2},
    Pages = {109--142},
    Title = {Coming to Know Principles in \mkbibemph{Posterior Analytics} II 19},
    Volume = {30},
    Year = {1997}}
@book{bolotin:1998,
    Annote = {copied only the first chapter},
    Author = {David Bolotin},
    Location = {Albany},
    Publisher = {State University of New York Press},
    Subtitle = {With Particular Attention to the Role of His Manner of Writing},
    Title = {An Approach to Aristotle's Physics},
    Year = {1998}}
@inproceedings{broadie:2004,
    Author = {Sarah Broadie},
    Pages = {123--150},
    Crossref = {dehaas:mansfeld:2004},
    Subtitle = {Distinguishing Alteration -- Substantial Change, Elemental Change, and First Matter in \mkbibemph{GC}},
    Title = {\mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I.4}}
@inproceedings{bruschnwig:2004,
    Author = {Jacques Brunschwig},
    Crossref = {dehaas:mansfeld:2004},
    Pages = {25--63},
    Subtitle = {A False Start?},
    Title = {\mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I.1}}
@proceedings{dehaas:mansfeld:2004,
    Editor = {{Frans A.\,J.} {de Haas} and Jaap Mansfeld},      Location = {Oxford},
    Publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    Title = {Aristotle's \mkbibemph{On Generation and Corruption} I},
    Year = {2004}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \newcommand{\mything}[3]{%
  \parindent 0pt
  \textbf{#1}\par
  \renewcommand\multicitedelim{\adddot\par}
  \parshape=2
    2em\dimexpr\hsize - 2em\relax
    4em\dimexpr\hsize - 4em\relax
  \fullcite[Texts:][]{#2}.
  \par
  \parshape=2
    2em\dimexpr\hsize - 2em\relax
    4em\dimexpr\hsize - 4em\relax
  \hspace*{-2em}%
  \fullcite[Literature:][]{#3}.
}


\begin{document}

\mything{Title text foo bar}%
{bayer:1997,bolotin:1998}%
{broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004,bayer:1997,bolotin:1998}

\mything{Title text foo bar}%
{bayer:1997,bolotin:1998}%
{broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004,bayer:1997,bolotin:1998}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of MWE]

Comment: I like this approach especially because you use the prenote of `\fullcite`. One thing that troubles me is that I may use more than only *two* bibkeys in the `fullcite`-value (e.g. `bayer:1997,bolotin:1998,broadie:2004,bruschnwig:2004` as #2). This, however, leads to unwanted results. Is there a way to tweak the `parshape`-modification accordingly so that it works for *any* number of bibkey's used? I tried around a bit but did not get it working. Something else: what if you use `\mything` again a second time (and a third time)? then the "Title text foo bar" (i.e. #1) is indented, too.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I hope this version is better and meets what you are looking for. (As you probably noticed, it would be easier to implement a similar thing where 'Texts:' and 'Literature:' appeared on a line of their own.)